# Preventing user from viewing another user profile in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have some question about my app. How can I prevent a user from viewing another user profile?
I mean, a user can only view their own profile. If user 123 is logged in, he is allowed in 'view&id=123' but denied in 'view&id=234' etc.

I know how to do this from the view page, but, am I able to deny it from my Controller? I'm thinking to use expression but I can't get it right. Here is my code

```
array('deny',
        'actions'=>array('view'),
        'expression'=>'$user->getName()!=??',
),
```

What is the right expression to replace the '??' part?
I tried to use $id (the actionView parameter) but it showed me an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this at controller level, I do something like this:

```
public function actionView($id){
 if($id != Yii::app()->user->id) {
    throw new CHttpException('403','You are not allowed to see this page');
 }

 //Continue with the code
}
```

Assumming that you've stored logged user id at the `Yii:app()->user` variable.

Also this might work:

```
array('deny',
    'actions'=>array('view'),
    'expression'=>'$_GET["id"] != Yii::app()->user->id',
),
```

Comment: Actually, I have tried this method before (and it's working).
But I'm curious whether I'm able to deny it from the accessRules function or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use option `allow` make it easier to get what you want.

```
         'actions' => ['view', 'list-post', 'unsubscribe'],
         'allow' => $_GET['id'] == Yii::$app->user->id,
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to create a custom filter (in application.components.controller, if you use it more than once):

```
public function filterCheckOwner($filterChain)
{
    if ($id=Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
    {        
        if($id != Yii::app()->user->id)
            throw new CHttpException('403','You are not allowed to see this page');
        else
            $filterChain->run();
    }
}
```

And then just add the actions that must run it in the filters() method with the same name (without 'filter'):

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'checkOwner + view, update, whatever', 
        ...
    );
}
```